# Why i am getting this error while i am using modifier property to set width or height of layout functions like surface or column,

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

[Modifier property error with width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdmPR.png)

i have using all things but never works

Comment: In the IDE you can check the kind of issue

Comment: add code in text format!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your imported package with：

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
```